# Datastore for scope "global" is not initialized

Tags: docker, consul

I want to use consul to set up a overlay network between two physical machines, but it failed so I try in just one machine first.
I do it like this:

1. `consul agent -server -bootstrap -data-dir /tmp/consul -bind=192.168.1.139 -node agent-one`
2. `docker network create -d overlay mynetwork`

But it gives me an error. I set `--cluster-store consul://localhost:8500 --cluster-advertise 192.168.1.139:2375` in `/etc/default/docker` and do `service docker restart`.

I have no idea about this.

> I used ubuntu,docker 1.13,consul 0.7.5